# Hiding Google AdMob Banner ( Is it ok? ) iOS SDK

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, admob

Is it ok to hide the Google AdMob Banner sometimes when i need some space?

Some ads are paid per impression and not per click. So will google realize that the banner is not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is against the Terms to hide the banner, especially on a pay per impression click.

Answer (score 3):

If you are paid *per impression*, I would assume that whatever Ad displaying library you're using is smart enough to know whether the frame is actually visible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer might be outdated.

In this [help thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/z08Noik39Tk) from 2018, Google's Mobile Ads SDK Team suggests that you may simply remove the view from its superview or set its `alpha` to 0:

> GADBannerView is simply an UIView and you can either use the alpha to
> zero or remove it from superview(). You can treat like you would treat
> any other UI element when it needs to be hidden and the SDK does not
> provide any specific APIs for this.
>
> It will request the Ad but will not count it as an impression of the Banner when View is hidden.